# Android App Invite

Tags: android, google-app-invites

I added android app invite feature to my app and everything is working fine and there is no error. but the thing is when I send invites always it shows the message "Message failed to send". Anyone has an idea about what's going on?

Comment: This might sound silly but if you are sending the invite as email, you would need internet, so do you have the internet permissions allowed?